# Table disappears when using selectionMode="single" in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I have a commandButton

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle.add}" icon="ui-icon-plus"
   actionListener="#{faPurMB.setFAInfoToTable}"
   style="width:100px;"
   update=":messageGrowl, fsFaInfo, tblAssetList" process="@this, fsFaInfo">
      <p:resetInput target="fsFaInfo" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And a dataTable

```
<p:dataTable id="tblAssetList" value="#{faPurMB.faInfoList}" 
   selectionMode="single"
   var="faList" rowIndexVar="rowSn" scrollable="true" rows="10"
   paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" >
</p:dataTable>
```

When I omit the selectionMode="single", data is added fine.  However, when I include it, the row disappears after clicking add.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set rowKey attribute into your table componet.
For example:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblAssetList" 
             value="#{faPurMB.faInfoList}" 
             selectionMode="single" 
             var="faList" 
             rowKey="#{faList.id}" ...>
```